# Is there a way to Inset two faces as one?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode

[image]

I'm trying to inset the two highlighted faces as one. I have already turned off individual and used scale in object mode as I saw recommended by others. However, I keep running into the same problem of the two faces insetting separately. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If you provide the file it'll be easier to tell but if you have turned ON the individual checkbox on the popup window and it's still not working then you might have an internal face between them. Turn on X ray mode (Button above the XYZ on the top right of the workspace) and see if that edge loop between them is a face.
If nothing works I guess you can merge the faces first (select both and Ctrl+X) and then inset them. You can then select the vertices of the edge you dissolved and press J to make a new edge between them

Comment: Or you have overlapping vertices and to fix that select all and press M > Merge by Distance

Comment: @Cornivius Thank you so much! This might be a stupid question but how do I tell if there is a face between them? I can also upload the file in another post if that would help.

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! I will try that

Comment: @Quirklesteins you can upload the file on blender stack exchange and put the link on the post by editing it.
If you are in X ray mode with the Face select mode, you should be able to see the face in there with this simple geometry. You can also go to the Select dropdown menu in edit mode, and hit Select->Select all by trait->Interior Faces. Then delete them with X-->Faces

Comment: Try hitting the I key twice with both faces selected in Edit mode.

Answer (score 4):

When you press <kbd>I</kbd> to [`Inset Faces`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html), you will notice that there are options shown at the top while you have not confirmed the Inset yet.

You can do the following in Inset mode:

- Toggle key <kbd>O</kbd> for Outset ON/OFF
- Toggle key <kbd>B</kbd> for Boundary ON/OFF
- Toggle key  <kbd>I</kbd> for Individual ON/OFF
- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to adjust the depth

In the following gif see how the values toggle to *ON* or *OFF* for these actions:

[image]

In your case make sure *Individual* is set to *OFF* by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> until the value is *OFF*. If for some reason it doesn't work, then you definitely have an issue with your mesh as mentioned in the comments. So in *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices then <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* to make sure you have no overlapping geometry and then try again.